# Why would I have to set CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource twice?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've updated a program to use Crystal Reports version 13.0.3500.0 and now the report will not display correctly. The report runs but shows ALL of the data. However, if I run it twice or put `rptViewer.ReportSource = rptDocument` twice in a row it will work perfectly. Why is this happening?

The report takes one parameter (date) and nothing changes between running it twice.

```
Dim StartDate = "2018-02-06"
Dim strReportPath As String = "\report path"    
Dim rptDocument As New ReportDocument
rptDocument.Load(strReportPath)

Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = StartDate
crParameterFieldDefinitions = rptDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("StartDate")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
rptViewer.ReportSource = rptDocument

'It works if I add this additional line below
'rptViewer.ReportSource = rptDocument
```

Comment: Does the report have any selection criteria in the Record Select Expert that may not be populated during the first call to ReportSource property?  It sounds like there is something out of scope when you load the report the first time, but is in scope when its loaded a second time.

Comment: @R.McMillan ahh, that was it. The selection formula was only in "Record Selection" and not "Saved Data Selection" too. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Record Select Expert to see if you have any selection criteria defined that may not be populated the first time the ReportSource property is called.  The problem you describe sounds as if the data needed for this selection criteria is not in scope during the first run of the report, but is in scope when the report runs a second time.